# Is it possible to overlay <label> over <h4>?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use one of the 'checkbox hacks' in which an accordion opens or closes when the user clicks on a label that toggles a checkbox.

The issue is that the webpage I am working on does not use labels, but rather h4 elements. So the user would be clicking on the h4 element to open/close the accordion. As far as I know, making this work directly is not possible. Or is it? I thought that maybe I could overlay an empty label over this h4 element, so that the user would be clicking on the label. Is that possible? Or is making a javascript accordion the only option here?

Comment: There is no need to use `label`. Add `click` listener to the `h4` element and toggle the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion how to do it:

```
 <body>  
        <!-- Add cursor : pointer to show the user he can click -->
        <h1 onClick="myFunc()" style="cursor: pointer;">test</h1>

        <script>
            // Do something here
            function myFunc(){
                console.log("title clicked")
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```